# Keen.io libraries for dashboard compatible with dataviz

Tags: javascript, dashboard, keen-io

I've been following the online examples (at https://github.com/keen/keen-dataviz.js/) and I'm successfully producing Dataviz pie-charts, using this keen-dataviz CDN library:

```
<script src="//d26b395fwzu5fz.cloudfront.net/keen-dataviz-1.1.3.js"></script>
```

(CDN is taken from example [here](https://github.com/keen/keen-dataviz.js/#install-the-library))

I'm now trying to add my pie-charts to a dashboard layout.

The [dashboard example](https://github.com/keen/dashboards/blob/gh-pages/layouts/quarter-grid/index.html) I'm following uses local js libaries rather than a CDN, e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/lib/keen-js/dist/keen.min.js"></script>
```

The local libraries in the dashboard github seem to include an older version of Dataviz (e.g. `.chartType` inplace of `.type`). I've been tweaking for ages (and have solved some problems) but I can't get my original pie-charts working with the dashboard. (Unfortunately my pie-charts query an internal data source so I can't give a working example...) But the bottom line is, these two libraries are incompatible...

My question is, is there an up-to-date dashboard js library I can use with the latest keen-dataviz.js library?

Answer (score 1):

The current open source dashboard template calls upon the previous [keen.js 3.0](https://github.com/keen/keen-js) instead of the newest [keen-dataviz.js](https://github.com/keen/keen-dataviz.js) library that you've discovered (best/better). This causes the syntax difference you're seeing for the chart options properties (`.type` instead of `.chartType`). I expect that the open source dashboard template you're using will be upgraded soon to keen-dataviz.js.

One solution you could try is, in addition to (or instead of) including keen.min.js you could also include keen-dataviz.js

```
<script src="https://d26b395fwzu5fz.cloudfront.net/keen-dataviz-1.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

Note these other two libraries may also be useful to include as well if you're going to collect data & analyze data with Keen:

```
<script src="https://d26b395fwzu5fz.cloudfront.net/keen-tracking-1.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d26b395fwzu5fz.cloudfront.net/keen-analysis-1.2.2.js"></script>
```

There are a couple additional resources you may also find helpful:

1. This dashboard template built for [Keen's Auto-Collector](https://keen.io/docs/streams/web-auto-collection/) using the latest keen-dataviz.js:

   - Repo on GitHub: https://github.com/keen/auto-collector-dashboard
   - Live View of Dashboard Template: https://autocollector-dashboard.glitch.me
2. Sample code for how to create a pie chart using keen.js:

   - https://github.com/keen/keen-js/blob/master/docs/visualization.md#pie-chart
3. This sample code on how to create a pie chart using keen-dataviz.js

   - JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/keen/5mbxzqhj/